# Playing Video in splashVC

Tags: ios, video

I have a `splashVC` and a homeVC. When I get into homeVC, I want that video is playing already.

How i do that?

Here is the `splashVC` method:

```
  - (void)presentCoverVC {
    CTCoverViewController *coverVC = [[CTCoverViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:coverVC animated:YES];
}
```

And method in homeVC:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.playerView];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"someURL"];
[self.playerView setVideoURL:URL];
[self.playerView prepareAndPlayAutomatically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create your player object and prepare during the application launch. When viewDidAppear of HomeVC called then just play video.